# Bit-Shift a String

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Im working on a simple encryptor for class and what Im trying to do is take in a message from the user as a String, scramble it then save the scrambled messege. I can figure out most parts of this, except that I would like to scramble the String by bit-shifting all the chars by a user set value.

So say I have:

```
    String msg="hello my name is blah blah";
    int userKey=6;
```

So how would I bit-shift the String by the value of the int?

Comment: Do you want to shift individual chars to convert `h` to `n` for instance? Or shift the whole String to one direction so that you get something like `h blahhellomynameisbla`? An example of the expected output would be really useful.

Comment: Why won't you use existing encryption algorithm with your personal `cipher` ? or any other requirements you have ?

Comment: Ah, the good old [classical ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_cipher) as used by Julius Ceasar and Napolen... ;)

Comment: im trying to shift the whole string one direction. Apologies if the question wasnt 100% clear, I was unsure if Im even pointing myself in the right direction :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to shift every char individually, you can try this snippet.-

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("hello my name is blah blah");
int userKey = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i ++) {
    msg.setCharAt(i, (char) (msg.charAt(i) + userKey));
}
```